# html in rvest verses htmlParse in XML

Tags: xml, r, rvest

As the following code shows, `html` in `rvest` package uses `htmlParse` from `XML` package. .

```
html
function (x, ..., encoding = NULL) 
{
    parse(x, XML::htmlParse, ..., encoding = encoding)
}
<environment: namespace:rvest>

htmlParse
function (file, ignoreBlanks = TRUE, handlers = NULL, replaceEntities = FALSE, 
    asText = FALSE, trim = TRUE, validate = FALSE, getDTD = TRUE, 
    isURL = FALSE, asTree = FALSE, addAttributeNamespaces = FALSE, 
    useInternalNodes = TRUE, isSchema = FALSE, fullNamespaceInfo = FALSE, 
    encoding = character(), useDotNames = length(grep("^\\.", 
        names(handlers))) > 0, xinclude = TRUE, addFinalizer = TRUE, 
    error = htmlErrorHandler, isHTML = TRUE, options = integer(), 
    parentFirst = FALSE) 
.....
```

So, for the following url:

```
 myurl<-"http://www.nepalstock.com.np/"
parse_XML<-htmlParse(myurl) #runs without error
parse_rvest<-html(myurl) # throws out the Internal Sever error
Error in parse.response(r, parser, encoding = encoding) : 
  server error: (500) Internal Server Error
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset the default user-agent from the underlying `httr::GET` request, then it works:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
parse_rvest <- html(myurl, add_headers("User-Agent" = "myagent"))
```

or

```
parse_rvest <- html(myurl, user_agent("myagent"))
```

Note that for debugging purposes, you can add `verbose()` to `html(...)`.

### Add:

Using the new `rvest` / `xml2` / `curl` combo, it should look like:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(curl)
parse_rvest <- curl(myurl, handle = new_handle("useragent" = "myua")) %>%
               read_html()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still throws an error: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 500.`.

Comment: Not here (Windows 7 x64, R version 3.1.3, rvest_0.2.0, httr_0.6.1, RCurl_1.95-4.6, XML_3.98-1.1)

Comment: Mine is (windows 8 x64 R version 3.2, rvest  ‘0.2.0.9000’ httr 0.6.1 RCurl: 1.95.4.6’, XML,‘3.98.1.2’). I also noticed that `html` is deprecated now.

Comment: A solution that worked for me is this (using `read_html`): `read_html(GET(myurl,user_agent("myagent")))`.

Comment: Either this way, or see my edit. `curl` may become the new `RCurl` / `httr`.

Comment: I was getting "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 401." but only behind my company's firewall.