# Using R2HTML with rvest/xml2

Tags: xml, r, rvest

I was reading [this](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/04/21/xml2/) blog post on the new package XML2. Previously, `rvest` used to depend on `XML`, and it made a lot of work easier for me (at least) by combining functions in two packages: e.g., I would use `htmlParse` from XML package when I can't read HTML page using `html` (now they called `read_html`).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897852/html-in-rvest-verses-htmlparse-in-xml) for an example, and then I can use `rvest` functions like `html_nodes`, `html_attr` on the parsed page. Now, with `rvest` depending on `XML2` this is not possible (at least on the surface).

I was just wondering what is the basic difference between XML and XML2. Other than attributing the author of XML package in the [post](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/04/21/xml2/) I mentioned earlier, the author of package doesn't explain the differences between XML and XML2.

Another example:

```
library(R2HTML) #save page as html and read later
library(XML)
k1<-htmlParse("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897852/html-in-rvest-verses-htmlparse-in-xml")
head(getHTMLLinks(k1),5) #This works

[1] "//stackoverflow.com"           "http://chat.stackoverflow.com" "http://blog.stackoverflow.com" "//stackoverflow.com"          
[5] "http://meta.stackoverflow.com"

# But, I want to save HTML file now in my working directory and work later

HTML(k1,"k1") #Later I can work with this
rm(k1)
#read stored html file k1
head(getHTMLLinks("k1"),5)#This works too 

[1] "//stackoverflow.com"           "http://chat.stackoverflow.com" "http://blog.stackoverflow.com" "//stackoverflow.com"          
[5] "http://meta.stackoverflow.com"

#with read_html in rvest package, this is not possible (as I know)
library(rvest)
library(R2HTML)
k2<-read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897852/html-in-rvest-verses-htmlparse-in-xml")

#This works
df1<-k2 %>%
html_nodes("a")%>%
html_attr("href")

head(df1,5)
[1] "//stackoverflow.com"           "http://chat.stackoverflow.com" "http://blog.stackoverflow.com" "//stackoverflow.com"          
[5] "http://meta.stackoverflow.com"

# But, I want to save HTML file now in my working directory and work later
HTML(k2,"k2") #Later I can work with this
rm(k2,df1)
#Now extract webpages by reading back k2 html file
#This doesn't work
k2<-read_html("k2") 

df1<-k2 %>%
html_nodes("a")%>%
html_attr("href")

df1
character(0)
```

Updates:

```
#I have following versions of packages loaded: 
lapply(c("rvest","R2HTML","XML2","XML"),packageVersion)
[[1]]
[1] ‘0.2.0.9000’

[[2]]
[1] ‘2.3.1’

[[3]]
[1] ‘0.1.1’

[[4]]
[1] ‘3.98.1.2’
```

I am using Windows 8, R 3.2.1., and RStudio 0.99.441.

Comment: This worked fine for me. I just installed the latest dev version of `rvest`. Maybe you should update yours as well (`R2HTML_2.3.1`,`rvest_0.2.0.9000`,`xml2_0.1.1`)

Comment: @MrFlick: I am using the same versions as yours. It runs but as you see in the post, it gives `character(0)` as an output.

Comment: I cannot replicate. I'm assuming you installed rvest from the github repo. During development the version number doesn't seem to change. I still suggest you try re-installing from the repo to get the latest version. Also, perhaps post what OS you are on, what R version (basically your `sessionInfo()` in case this is an edge case).

Comment: I have updated the post. Yes, you are correct; I have installed `rvest` from github.

Comment: I have reinstalled the `rvest` but I get the same output (not solved yet).

Comment: When I save the html file from rvest, the size is only 1 Kb verses 78 Kb from XML. I guess difference has to do with this.

Comment: Try defining `HTML.xml_document<-function(x, ...) HTML(as.character(x),...)` Or better why, why are you using `R2HTML` rather than just writing out the data with `write_xml()` instead?

Comment: Thanks. I used `write_xml()` and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `R2HTML` package just seems to `capture.out` on the XML object and then writes that back to disk. This doesn't seem like a robust way to save HTML/XML data back to disk. The reason the two might be different is that `XML` data print out differently than `xml2` data. You could define a function to call `as.character()` rather than relying on `capture.output`

```
HTML.xml_document<-function(x, ...) HTML(as.character(x),...)
```

Or you probably could skip with `R2HTML` altogether and write out the `xml2` data directly with `write_xml`.

And maybe the best approach would be to download the file first and then import it.

```
download.file("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897852/html-in-rvest-verses-htmlparse-in-xml", "local.html")
k2 <- read_html("local.html")
```

Comment: Thanks . `download.file` is the good option (never had this is mind).