# Pass user_agent() parameter in read_html()

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I fail to understand how to pass a user agent to read_html().

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30899327/7114709) recommends the following code:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
parse_rvest <- html(myurl, user_agent("myagent"))
```

Additionally, I understand that html() is now replaced by read_html(). However, the following code:

```
parse_rvest <- read_html("http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/", 
                      user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0"))
```

returns an error:

```
Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=list; extent=7].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to do `user_agent = "user agent"`, not `user_agent("user-agent")`

Here's a reprex to demonstrate:

```r
library(httr)
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2

parse_rvest <- read_html("http://testing-ground.scraping.pro/", 
                      user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0")
parse_rvest
#> {html_document}
#> <html class="no-js">
#> [1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 ...
#> [2] <body>\n\t\t<script type="text/javascript">\n\t\t\n\t\t  var _gaq = _gaq  ...
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>